# Special condition syntax with parentheses and brackets

Tags: python

Is there any explanation about the following Python condition syntax?

```
>>> a = 10
>>> s = (0, 1)[a<10]
>>> print s
0
>>> a = -10
>>> s = (0, 1)[a<10]
>>> print s
1
```

It seems to work like an `if` statement. Why does this work?

Comment: This would be written by anyone sane as `s = 1 if a < 10 else 0`! Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/470376/3001761

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python, [`bool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bool) is a subclass of [`int`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int).

```
>>> issubclass(bool, int)
True
```

In other word, `False` is equal to 0, and `True` is equal to 1:

```
>>> False == 0
True
>>> True == 1
True
```

So they can be used as a index:

```
>>> ['No', 'Yes'][False]  # ['No', 'Yes'][0]
'No'
>>> ['No', 'Yes'][True]   # ['No', 'Yes'][1]
'Yes'
```

The expression `a < 10` yields `True` or `False` based on the value of `a`. So `(0, 1)[a < 10]` will yield `0` or `1` accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

`(0, 1)` is a 2-element [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple). You can access its values using the [index accessors](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) `[0]` and `[1]` like this:

```
>>> (0, 1)[0]
0
>>> (0, 1)[1]
1
```

Now, in Python, the boolean values [`True`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#True) and [`False`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#False) are actually instances of `int` (because `bool` is a subtype of `int`):

```
>>> issubclass(bool, int)
True
>>> isinstance(True, int)
True
>>> isinstance(False, int)
True
```

The int values of `True` and `False` are `1` and `0`:

```
>>> True == 1
True
>>> False == 0
True
```

So you can actually use them two access the elements in your 2-element tuple:

```
>>> (0, 1)[False]
0
>>> (0, 1)[True]
1
```

And that explains why specifying a condition there—which returns a boolean—will work as well.

This is also mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-boolean-values) (emphasis mine):

> Boolean values are the two constant objects `False` and `True`. They are used to represent truth values (although other values can also be considered false or true). **In numeric contexts (for example when used as the argument to an arithmetic operator), they behave like the integers 0 and 1, respectively.**